# Android ImageButton doesnt change on focus

Tags: java, android, xml, imagebutton

I have 4 buttons, they are all image buttons with "@null" as background.

In the xml file I have:

```
 <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/buttonimgplay" android:id="@+id/imageButton1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:onClick="startGame"  android:background="@null"></ImageButton>
```

buttonimgplay is another xml file containing this:

```
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_pressed="true"
       android:drawable="@drawable/playpressed" /> <!-- pressed -->
 <item android:state_focused="true"
       android:drawable="@drawable/playabitpressed" /> <!-- focused -->
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/playnotpressed" /> <!-- default -->
```

However, when the user presses the button on the screen it doesnt change, as it switches view to something else. on buttons i havent initialised (ie attached a method) yet this image switching works fine.

Any ideas how I can get the image on the button to change before the view is changed?

Thanks,

Ben

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding state_selected to your statelist as well?  I don't remember if I had the exact same scenario, but I know that I had to start adding this to some of my state list drawables to get them to work, and I believe it was exactly what you're experiencing.

```
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_pressed="true"
       android:drawable="@drawable/playpressed" /> <!-- pressed -->
 <item android:state_focused="true"
       android:drawable="@drawable/playabitpressed" /> <!-- focused -->
 <item android:state_selected="true"
       android:drawable="@drawable/playabitpressed" /> <!-- selected -->
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/playnotpressed" /> <!-- default -->
```

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work, thanks though. As soon as I press the button it just switches view, no image switch at all :s

Comment: If I hold down the button it changes image, just not if I press it normally.

Comment: maybe it's taking too long to load?  what do you mean by "switches view"?

Comment: I mean in the onClick it does this:  setContentView(new OtherView(this));

Comment: You may need to add the android:focusable="true" attribute to your image button.